# How can I prevent horizontal scrolling in VS Code when selecting rectangular blocks of code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

A feature I tend to use a lot is the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> feature of selecting multiple lines of code with multiple cursors, and got used to it in VS. With VS Code, however, I can't scroll down (using the mouse wheel) while using such a feature; horizontal scrolling happens instead because I'm pressing Shift. How to enable vertical scrolling in such a situation?

I tried searching the web for an answer, changed keyboard preferences in VS Code, disabling horizontal scroll with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>; none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the scrolling before pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>.

Put your caret at the beginning point (one end / corner of the rectangular text space you want to be selected), then do the scrolling until you can see the other end / corner without moving the caret, then press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> and click the other end / corner of the text space you want to be selected.

Comment: I'm used to scrolling while pressing alt + shift, though... there should be a way

Comment: you're a stubborn one :P